# Should I work more than the mentioned working days in my job contract?

Tags: contract-law, employment, germany, salary

I am working in German company and my job contract states following:

> Der Arbeitnehmer erhält für die unter vorstehend Ziff. II. näher bezeichnete Tätigkeit ein Brutto**gehalt** in Höhe von X Euro bei 21 Arbeitstagen,.....
>
> > The employee receives a gross [**monthly**] salary of X euros for 21 working days for the activity described in more detail under II

and for the holidays it mentions:

> Der Arbeitnehmer erhält pro Kalendarjahr Anspruch auf 24 Arbeitstage Urlaub bein einer 5 Tage Woche.
>
> > The employee is entitled to 24 working days of vacation per calendar year with a 5-day week.

I have been working for past 1 year for the whole calendar month, regardless of number of working days. I just noticed that in February, 2022 I was paid only for 20 days as there were only 20 working days. But in March, 2022 we have 23 working days but I am only being paid for 21 days. This has been happening for past year or so.

Am I entitled for a compensation for the extra hours I put in. I am not sure, but sometimes I feel like my boss exploits my situation as I do not understand German law the way he does.

Could someone who has an understanding on this topic enlighten me?

Edit 1: Added scanned version of page discussing about salary and bonuses.
[image]

Comment: Are you able to translate your quotes as [all (,most) posts are expected to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/906208)

Comment: @Rick "*Are you able to translate your quotes*" That seems pointless. A person who does not speak German is unlikely to be knowledgeable of German labor law, the latter being crucial for assessing the parties' position.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Hmm, that assumes that only native speakers are eligible to offer an answer. I have no way of knowing for sure, but I will make the assumption that many of the users who provide excellent answers for the non-English speaking jurisdiction tags are not fluent in that jurisdiction's language.

Comment: @Rick "*that assumes that only native speakers are eligible to offer an answer.*" Not at all. My point is that proficiency in a language usually is a prerequisite for understanding the subtleties of legislation and court decisions enacted/released in that language. Proficiency does not depend on being a native speaker of that language.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I've asked a [Meta question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1412/35069) to avoid cluttering up this post any more than needs be.

Answer (score 2):

You are receiveing a **monthly salary** (**Gehalt**) (as apposed to a **hourly wage** (**Lohn**)), based on a 5 day work week with a yearly average of 21 days per month

- 21.6666=((52*5)/12)

This sum doesn't take national holidays into account.

The **average** amount is based on the 9 holidays common in all states (most actually have more than 9).

The exact formel for the average amount of working days per month is:

- days=(((days_of_year-(**days_free_per_week***52))-**holidays_per_year**)/months_per_year)

  - 21=(((365-(**2***52))-**9**)/12)

Source: [Arbeitstage pro Monat errechnen - Arbeitsrecht 2022](https://www.arbeitsrechte.de/arbeitstage-pro-monat/#Wie_viele_Arbeitstage_pro_Monat_gibt_es_im_Durchschnitt)

You will be paid the monthly sum even if you only work 20 days (due to holidays etc. within one month) or 22 days.

If you had a contract based on **Lohn**, you would only be paid for each actual hour you worked.

The word **Entgelt** is now often used instead of **Gehalt** and **Lohn**, but the distinction between hourly, monthly still exists.

---

> - **Stundenlohn**: Wird im Arbeitsvertrag festgelegt, dass jede **tatsächlich geleistete Arbeitsstunde** entgolten wird, kann das Gehalt am Monatsende entsprechend der gearbeiteten Stunden **variieren**.
> - **Monatsgehalt**: Das klassische Gehalt wird **monatlich ausgezahlt**, **ohne** dass es darauf ankommt, wie viele Sonn- oder Feiertage in einem Monat anfallen, oder wie lang dieser ist.
>
> > - **Hourly wage**: If the employment contract stipulates that **every hour actually worked** is remunerated, the salary at the end of the month can vary according to the hours worked.
> > - **Monthly salary**: The classic salary is **paid monthly**, **regardless** of how many Sundays or public holidays occur in a month or how long it is.

---

The agreed monthy sum of the contract should **always** be listed, every month, as one position in the monthly pay slip

- shown in the image below as: **Gehalt**: 3.151,00

The other positions could vary, month to month, resulting in a different final monthly sum (**Steuerpfl. Bruttolohn**)

- but **Gehalt** should always be the same every month

Any fluctuation you may have should be from the other positions in the pay slip.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mark. Your comment makes a lot of sense, as my contract talks about Bruttogehalt rather than Stundenlohn with 40 working hours per week. But I think it still entitles me X amount for the February, regardless of how many working days there were?

Comment: @RishikMani From the text you have quoted, with the word **gehalt** you should recieve the same amount every month unless the contract **explicidly** states otherwise. Maybe you should add the rest of the sentence/paragraph, since from what can be seen it does not state that and therefore there should be no reduction for February. A contract can override the default rules ([Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch - §611a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__611a.html)), but must be clearly stated. What is not stated in a contract, then the general rules definded elsewhere apply.

Comment: "*You are receiveing [...] based on a 5 day work week*". For that to be true, the first clause would have to be in terms of "5-day work week" just like the *Urlaub* clause. Instead, the first clause is in terms of 21 days, and there is no indication in the OP's description that it shall be interpreted as the "average" of 21 days per month.

Comment: @RishikMani For clarification: when do you recieve payment? A **Gehalt** must be paid by that last working day of the month. **Lohn** by the 15th of the next month, since time is needed to calculate the amount of hours to be paid.

Comment: @IñakiViggers What is not defined in a contract, then the default value is taken. The formel for the average 5 day week is: 21=((365-(2*52)-9)/12). [Arbeitstage pro Monat errechnen - Arbeitsrecht 2022](https://www.arbeitsrechte.de/arbeitstage-pro-monat/#Wie_viele_Arbeitstage_pro_Monat_gibt_es_im_Durchschnitt)

Comment: "*What is not defined in a contract, then the default value is taken.*" Absolutely, but draftsman's switch of terms between the 1st and 2nd clauses precludes the notion you point out. *Contra proferentem* would decide the ambiguity (see BGB §305c) or the sum of the OP's details suggests that he is entitled to the extra compensation.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, till now I get the payments on the last day of the month, if it is not a working day, then probably the last working day of the month. But the contract also mentions that the payment could be made latest till 6th of the coming month.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I will try to upload the snapshot of the page today if it helps.

Comment: @RishikMani Also take a look at your pay slips. The sum agreed to in the contract should be shown **every** month.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I just updated the question with the scanned copy. Also for past 5 - 6 months the income has been fluctuating heavily. No two months had I the same income which made me ask question here. For example, February says work hour is 160 and March says 161. It should always sum up to 168 hours.

Comment: @RishikMani Is the agreed monthy sum of the contract **always** listed as one position in the monthly pay slip? Any fluctuation should be from other positions in the pay slip. The agreed monthy sum should be **constant for every month**. §3(4) shows that you have a 40 hour work week and anything more in one week can be used in the next week (42+38=80). Your work week is MO-FR. You are expected to work on every MO-FR of each month. Any public holiday on a MO-FR will be booked as if you worked.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I do not understand what exactly you mean by always listed, but Betrag (Net monthly) shows different amount atleast in February and March.

Comment: @RishikMani See added image at the bottom of the answer, which will hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson thank you very much for the image. Mine looks a bit different but I got your point. In my salary slip I see definitely a listing of Stundenlohn (which I am now confused, as it implies hourly wages as opposed to Brutto mentioned in contract).  Also for Mar it is for 163 hours, for Feb only 160 hours while for December had 168 hours. This "Menge" (measurement) of hours is confusing me.

Comment: @RishikMani Then this should be looked into by a professionel, since thebpay slips don't match the binding contract. Do have a Betriebsrat? If yes, have them look into this.

Comment: @MarkJohnson thank you for all your efforts. I really appreciate for continuous support. I will try to find some one and will update here if I get something.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just clarify what "working the whole calendar month" means: Monday to Friday, or also Saturday / Sunday? Did you take your 24 days holidays? Usually you can carry only a few days holidays over to the next year, and whatever is carried over is lost end of March. Plus there are quite a few public holidays where you shouldn't be working. (I think 10 or 11 days, but you lose the day if it is on a weekend).

Normally you would get paid monthly. A month has 20 to 23 working days, minus whatever public holidays there are (they are paid). The normal thing is that people get paid the same amount every month. Plus you get paid on the holidays that you are taking. So you should be working 52 weeks times 5 days = 260 days, minus on average 8 day public holidays (for example its fewer if Christmas is on Saturday / Sunday and you don't get extra days, and its more if Christmas is on working days), minus 24 days holidays = about 228 days.

It would be unusual to get paid more in a month with 22 or 23 working days, but it would also be very unusual to be paid less in a 20 day month.

Comment: By whole calendar month I meant all working days of the company. Our working days are Monday - Friday, plus I still have 3 holidays left. Atleast in February and March there are no government holidays on workdays (Monday - Friday), which means either I'd be paid for 21 days in February or 23 days in March. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. The _normal_ way is that as an employee you are paid a monthly salary, which is the same every month, independent on how many days are worked in that month. As a contractor, you may send in a bill every month which lists either hours or days worked, but not as an employee

Comment: Only partially relevant to OPs question, but in German law, leftover holidays are not 'lost' at the end of March. Employers are legally required to pay out any holidays not taken. In practice most employers have no interest in doing so and hence require their employees to actually take the remaining holidays before they would expire.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I entitled for a compensation for the extra hours I put in.

Apparently you are.

The first excerpt is in terms of 21 days rather than monthly compensation. Your transcription does not reflect that the clause has any qualifiers or constraints that address the foreseeable variation of work days in a month. This is in contrast with the second excerpt, which is in terms of calendar year. Accordingly, the compensation for each day you work (or take the paid time-off to which you are entitled) is X/21 €.

That being said, you need to ascertain whether other terms in the contract supersede the presumption enacted in section §612(1) of the [Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/BGB.pdf).

The employer's possible allegation that the extra hours are not part of your written contract will be unavailing. That is because section §611a prescribes that all the surrounding circumstances are to be considered for ascertaining whether the matter, in this case the extra hours you worked, amounts to an employment contract.

Comment: The use of the word **Gehalt** shows that this is a monthly compensation and not based on the actual time worked.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "*not based on the actual time worked.*" The employer's mention of 21 days introduced an ambiguity. That ambiguity may strike the presumption that the term Gehalt in the OP's contract refers to something besides *Zahlungszeitpunkt*, i.e.,the *schedule* of salary payments. [This article](https://www.nettolohn.de/magazin/gehalt/lohn-oder-gehalt-der-unterschied-liegt-im-detail.html) explains that also the amount paid as Gehalt can vary ("*Es gibt auch Gehaltsempfänger, deren Entgelt variiert. [...] Der Status des Gehalts wird durch die flexibeln Zusatzszahlungen nicht angetastet.*").

Comment: As your quote states the **Gehalt** remains the same, independent of extra payments that may vary. The 20% extra for night duty, will only be paid for the time you actualy have night duty. So the final sum (on top of the Gehalt) may vary.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "*As your quote states the Gehalt remains the same*" That is not what the quote says. What remains the same is the *status*, i.e. classification, as Gehalt.

Comment: The status has not changed means: the **monthly payment** (Gehalt) agreed to in the contract is not effected.

Comment: (-1) The two sentences togeather state: **monthly payment** (Gehalt) of sum X, based on a 5 day week (21 working days) and 24 working days of vacation based on the 5 day week. Nothing is stated in the 2 sentences about a reduction or increase of the monthly payment where there is more or less than 21 working days in a specific month. This is a standard contract. I see no grounds for compensation that this answer claims exists.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "*The two sentences togeather state:*" You are trying to rewrite the 1st clause. Nowhere does the actual clause say "5 day week". Only the 2nd clause does. I would agree with you only if the 1st clause made no mention of "21 working days", since that would leave no room for discrepancies between 5-day weeks and the variable number of work days in a month. If "21 work days" and "5 day week" were synonymous, there would be no need for the employer to employ the latter term in the 2nd clause. Courts supposedly reject interpretations that render the terms of a contract redundant.